html object tag and firefox NS_ERROR_WONT_HANDLE_CONTENT
I have a simple html:
<object data="MY_INTERNAL_URL">Couldn't load</object> 
Firefox does not display the file under MY_URL nor it shows the fallback 'Couldn't load' message. In developer console I can see that due to some reason my URL load fails with NS_ERROR_WONT_HANDLE_CONTENT. The content can be a .txt file or a .mp3 (maybe some others too).
The response headers look ok too:
HTTP/1.1 200  content-disposition: attachment; filename*=utf-8''filename.mp3 pragma: cache cache-control: must-revalidate Content-Type: audio/mpeg;charset=utf-8 Content-Length: 8377 Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2024 07:57:24 GMT
I am unable to find any reasonable info about this error or how to force the fallback behaviour in this case.
I tried finding a way of detecting whether the url for object loads, but could not find any way. The onError callback is not called in this case.

Can you try with a resource that does not have a content-disposition header, and see if that changes anything?

Not straight away, as the URL is not I an server that I control, but this is something I planned on checking. But even if it is this reason it would not help me much, as I can't request the owner to change these headers. Anyway I would expect the fallback to work anyway in this case.

"as I can't request the owner to change these headers" - with MY_INTERNAL_URL in your example, I would have assumed these are local assets. Can't you ask the owner for cooperation in general (because you are actually trying to use content you're not supposed to to begin with?), or do you just think they won't change anything, because they need those headers in a different scenario? If the latter, then you could perhaps agree on an additional URL parameter to control that behavior.

I would like to concentrate on the technical problem here. I appreciate the approach you are suggesting but if I had questions relating this solution (how to request in another company such a change on server side) I guess I would post at a different site of stackoverflow.

If the response headers are indeed the problem, then I suppose you could use a web worker or service worker, to manipulate those ...
